# how to ignore __repr__() for certain method but not others

Tags: python, jupyter

sorry I am not quite sure how to put the title more accurately.

I have a class with `__repr__()` to report the some key attributes of class.

Most of my methods return self, so that I can daisy-chain methods. e.g. `a.m1().m2()...`

```
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = "hello"

    def __repr__(self):
        msg = f"Myclass: a = {self.a}, b is {self.b}."
        return msg

    def plus(self, n):
        self.a += n
        return self

    def concat(self, s):
        self.b += s
        return self

    def play(self):
        # play audio here
        return self

ac = Myclass()
ac.plus(n=4)  # Ok i would like to see __repr__ output

ac.play()  # no I dont want to see __repr__
```

The `__repr__` works great in Jupyter as it can give me a report on some key attributes by just executing `ac`. However, I have a `play()` method to play the audio, which also return self, and I absolutely do not want the print to execute as sometime I might need to call this method multiple times quickly.

So is there a way to have `return self` in all my methods, but not call `__repr__` on return?

Many thanks

Comment: err, assign to something? `_ = ac.play()` ?

Comment: ah good idea, does it affect the speed in any way?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to have `return self` in the `play` method.

Comment: @wjandrea Sometimes it can be convenient to "chain" methods, like `ac.plus(n = 4).play().debug_info()` etc.

Comment: so that I can chain operate: a.play().do_something().play().plot()...

Comment: There are some rules for `__repr__`, you should enclose the output in angle brackets: `<...some useful description...>`. More in the docs (Data Model, object.__repr__)

Comment: `ac.play();` - the semicolon keeps `ipython/jupyter` from displaying the output, or assigning it to `Out` or `_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you assign the result to some variable, the interactive input doesn't call `__repr__`.

I'd do:

```
_ = ac.play()
```

using an anonymous `_` variable to make it clear that it's throwaway, which also keeps the interactive interpreter feature which stores any function result in `_` implicitly.

In terms of speed, yes, it's faster since `__repr__` isn't called, and `_` would be assigned no matter what.

Comment: I like this because if you don't do anything, the interactive interpreter will usually assign the result to `_` anyway. So there is really no difference in behavior.

Comment: yeah, I was just adding that to my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

> `ac.play();` - the semicolon keeps IPython/Jupyter from displaying the output, or assigning it to `Out` or `_`.

from [hpaulj's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56727145/how-to-ignore-repr-for-certain-method-but-not-others#comment100014833_56727145)

Comment: This is also a great way . Thanks